# Driver for Xerox Workcentre PE114E for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Oops, there seems to be no driver.
Could you recommend me some driver for a similar device?

Answer (score 2):

Since they have no specific Windows 7 drivers, I would suggest trying the Vista driver in its place.

http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-pe114e/downloads/enin.html?operatingSystem=winvista&fileLanguage=en_GB

Comment: The printer is now printing. But as for the scanner, it is not working. Windows said that no driver compatible with x64 processors is found.

Comment: if you absolutely need the scanner, i know a paid software called VueScan which should get the job done..

Comment: Have you tried the 64bit Vista driver? http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-pe114e/downloads/enin.html?operatingSystem=winvistax64&fileLanguage=en_GB

Comment: This works far more often than you think, since Vista and Seven are pretty similar under the hood.